# Detect delivery of whatsapp message using selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, bots, whatsapp, browser-automation

I had a whatsapp bot that send images and videos, but I couldn't get a way to ensure the attachements are sent.
I have tried several ways to solve the problem, this is the last idea that I had is to open the dropdown menu above the last message and check if the delivered box has the word 'today' in it.

```
try:
    menu = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#main > div._3B19s > div > div._5kRIK > div.n5hs2j7m.oq31bsqd.gx1rr48f.qh5tioqs > div:nth-child(14) > div > div > div > div._1BOF7._2AOIt > span > div > div > span').click()
    msg_info = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#app > div > span:nth-child(4) > div > ul > div > li:nth-child(1) > div')
    status = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="app"]/div/div/div[6]/span/div/span/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div')
            if 'today' in status.text():
    return True
except NoSuchElementException:
    return False
```

The problem with this code is that the menu is not clickable at the moment, it require hovering over it to be clickable
Is there any way to solve this problem or just define the state of the icon at the bottom of the message directly?

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to solve your problem.

The first way is to use actions in Selenium. You can achieve this using the following code:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
actions = ActionChains(driver)
actions.move_to_element(element)
action.click(element)
#Any other steps
actions.perform()
```

This code will move the mouse cursor to the center of the element, and then you can click it. You can learn more about action_chain [here](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#module-selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains)

The second and more direct way to check whether a message has been sent or not is by inspecting the HTML of your WhatsApp element. Here's the relevant HTML snippet:

```
<span aria-label="Read" data-icon="msg-dblcheck" class="k17s6i4e">
```

As you can see, there is an attribute named 'aria-label.' After getting the element, you can check this attribute to determine whether the message has been sent or not. Here's an example of how you can do that:

```
message_status = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'actual css').get_attribute('aria-label')
```